# Input focus in a setTimout not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have a text input and a small script to focus on it after a few seconds:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  debugger; //Emulates a breakpoint
  document.getElementById("textinput").focus();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textinput">
```

In Chrome v68, if I put a breakpoint on the line starting with `document` and waiting a few seconds before resume, after pressing F8 to resume the script the input isn't focused anymore. In Firefox even without breakpoint, it is randomly focused or not. What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, a `breakpoint` will pause the script execution. Is it working once you resume it?

Comment: For a start, add `console.log(document.getElementById("textinput").value)` in the timeout function, so you'll know - a. Is the timeout function called. b. Does it get the `input`.

Comment: @Zenoo Sorry forgot to mention, I resumed the script after waiting a few seconds with the  breakpoint activated.

Comment: @neptune I added a snippet demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @31piy Run it with the DevTools opened, it doesn't work for me on the latest Chrome.

Comment: @31piy wait a few seconds before resuming with F8.

Comment: Do you, by chance, set back the focus to your document/widnow? debugger might lose it.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm not doing any additional thing beside running that short script with devtools opened and pressing F8.

Comment: Then you need to set the focus back to your window. When you press F8, your devtools panel has the focus, and you won't be able to see that the input has indeed gained the focus at this time. You can check this by adding a `console.log(document.activeElement)`